# Change document before a function ends

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to modify and update a document before a Javascript function has ended? For example (not what I'm actually doing, but close enough):

```
function longloop(){
    for(var i=0;i<100;i++){
        x = someLengthyFunction();
        document.getElementById('aTable').innerHTML+='<tr><td>' + x + '</td></tr>';
    }
}
```

That function gets called by a button press, and I'd like to update a table as the loop progresses. What I have up there will only show the updated table when the loop has finished.

Comment: No need for IE, this is just for a side project.

Comment: Alright, then just be aware of one other thing. By doing `.innerHTML += '<tr><td>...'` in the loop, what you're doing in each iteration is getting the HTML string representation of the table content, adding a row to it, then overwriting all the content based on the new string. So basically in each iteration you're destroying all the previous elements that were created and recreating all of them plus one more row. This is *extremely* expensive. Just FYI. :o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is not possible.

What you have to do is to split up the loop in parts, and use `window.setTimeout` to continue with the next part after updating the document.

Example:

```
function longloop(){
  function work(i) {
    x = someLengthyFunction();
    document.getElementById('aTable').innerHTML+='<tr><td>' + x + '</td></tr>';
    i++;
    if (i < 100) window.setTimeout(function(){ work(i); }, 0);
  }
  work(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely a job for [web workers](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-workers/current-work/). You would run the above script as a worker which would pass messages at intervals to update your content. But since only very modern browsers can take advantage of web workers, and JavaScript is not a threaded language, you may have to write that loop very creatively to get this done.